# Error: zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints on Azure

Tags: wcf, azure

I have a running, mature WCF service that I am trying to deploy on Windows Azure as a Web Role (with a custom wrapper, of course). My RoleEntryPoint.OnStart() method creates a ServiceHost instance, where it trips with the zero application endpoints error. The configuration (`web.config`) service model section is:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Linguasys.QualitativeAnalysis.Processing" behaviorConfiguration="defaultServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="wcfAzureWrapperStoryMapping.StoryMapperAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Linguasys.QualitativeAnalysis.IProcessing" />
<!--
        <endpoint address="soap" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Linguasys.QualitativeAnalysis.IProcessing" />
-->
  </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="wcfAzureWrapperStoryMapping.StoryMapperAspNetAjaxBehavior">
  <!--
          <enableWebScript />
          -->
          <webHttp faultExceptionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding></webHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding></basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <!--
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="StoryMapper.svc" service="Linguasys.QualitativeAnalysis.Processing"/>
      </serviceActivations>
      -->
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Never mind the activation bits, the basic HTTP binding, etc. They were added later to see whether it will work.

I see that my `web.config` ends up at the `siteroot` and `approot` and all the other places.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RoleEntryPoint.OnStart() method runs in WaIISHost.exe which does not know anything about your web.config.  For more info see http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2010/12/02/new-full-iis-capabilities-differences-from-hosted-web-core/, and for information about how the processes run see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2011/05/05/windows-azure-role-architecture.aspx.

Two options:

1. Move your WCF configuration to WebRole1.dll.config (or whatever your role entry point binary's name is).  Make sure you set the .config to Content and copy local.
2. Instantiate your ServiceHost in w3wp (ie. Global.asax).

Comment: An extremely informative and helpful answer, thanks. I'll try it and let you know the outcome. That said, I keep seeing mentions of `web.config` everywhere, as in, "web roles use `web.config`, worker roles use `app.config`". Strange.

Comment: WebRoles do still use web.config to configure anything related to your web development (ie. standard web.config stuff).  Generally your WCF host is w3wp.exe so web.config would be correct.  Your scenario is much more custom.